# is there any efficient way to store numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy

i prepared an image dataset with Numpy array
and i need to store them as efficient as possible

ill give you an example

for 6 image its like **2.2 MB**

and after using [Numpy compressed format](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html?highlight=savez#numpy.savez_compressed) its over **7.5 MB**

this is what i come up with

```
 np.savez_compressed("./img.npz",images) # array of images
```

any way to improve that

Comment: Using`.npz` is also fine to save compressed numpy arrays, but I'd recommend you to take a look once at parquet file format. It compresses very well and data read/write speed is also high and memory footprint is less compared to other several file formats.

Comment: @ThePyGuy ill try that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use numpy's savetxt method

```python
from numpy import savetxt
```

Then you can save it as a CSV file (file might be large in size but efficient to load next) or you can do it as a simple ".txt" file

Example:

```python
x = y = z = np.arange(0.0,5.0,1.0)
np.savetxt('test.csv', x, delimiter=',') # CSV
np.savetxt('test.txt', x, delimiter=',') # TXT
```

You can choose your own delimiter also.

Comment: if save it as txt or csv can i load it directly to numpy array?

Comment: Yes. use this article https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/intro-to-earth-data-science/scientific-data-structures-python/numpy-arrays/import-txt-csv-files-numpy-arrays/

Comment: CSV is great for its readability and portability, but it is not more efficient than NPY or PNG.